# expectation of Log Noncentral Chi

Tags: expected-value, gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, non-central

Let $X$ follow [non central chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution), the formula of $\mathbb{E}[\log(X)]$ (or equivalently $\mathbb{E}[\log(X^2)]$ where $X^2$ is Non central chi square) can be found [here](http://moser-isi.ethz.ch/explog.html) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06266).

However, the formula contains polynomials that is complicated. I wonder if there is some approximation for this expectation.

Comment: Please post those sums in the body of your question. Also post your own attempts/thoughts. – *Reviewer*.

Comment: The first formula contains no infinite series: it's a polynomial.

Comment: @Jim My thought was that to calculate the expected value, I looked for the PDF and tried integrating it. That is what I wrote in the question. I don't see any other approachs. If it is obviously easy for you, what about give me some hints?

Comment: @whuber sorry, wrong words.

Comment: The distinction, though, is critical, isn't it?  The polynomial is readily evaluated and not "complicated."  This raises questions about what kind of "approximation" you seek and how well it should fit.  Help out your readers by editing the question to address these issues specifically.

Comment: @CathMaillon your question came up in a review queue. Hyperlinks rot away very easily and then your question can not be understood anymore.

Comment: @Jim ok I will add it.